# ng-repeat is not working inside ul in angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, codeigniter

My ng-repeat is not working inside ul.Please help me.

With this code

```
 <div ng-controller="user">
                <div ng-init="tender_in_state()" >
                    <ul ng-repeat="t in stateTender" >
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>tenderByState/{{t.id}}" >a</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

angular js user controller

```
$scope.stateTender = {};
$scope.tender_in_state = function() {
        Data.TenderInState().success(function(data) {
            $scope.stateTender = data;
            //alert();
        });
    }
```

Service request function

```
this.TenderInState = function ($data) {

    return $http.post(site_url + "User_controller/getTenderInStateList",$data);

};
```

In user controller

```
public function getTenderInStateList() {
    $data[] = $this->service->getTenderInStateList($data);
    echo json_encode($rs);

}
```

In service model

```
public function getTenderInStateList($id){
    $rs = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('et_state')
            ->where('id',$id)
            ->get()->row();
    return $rs;

}
```

Can anyone help me to getting the issue

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat goes on element that will be repeated. In your case on "li" element.
What errors did you get? Doesn't print nothing or repeat the "ul" element or even something else?

PS: Sorry my bad english

Comment: If you call directly the url, the response comes right?

If you put a console.log, the data content are correct?

 Data.TenderInState().success(function(data) {
     console.lo(data); // what this prints on console?
     $scope.stateTender = data;
     //alert();
});